# Is Selenium Click or Keys.Enter or MovtoElement.Click() a soft click?

Tags: selenium, fiddlercore

My test automation uses Selenium for UI interactions and fiddlercore api to capture the events generated by UI. Situation I am facing right now is fiddlercore is failing to capture event that is caused by click on a button. I have tried following ways:

```
builder.MoveToElement(searchButton).Click(searchButton).Build().Perform();   
searchButton.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
searchButton.Click();
```

None of these could generate that event. When I click them actually I am able to see that specific event. Are these all soft clicks and could that be the reason of not able to get that event?

Comment: What is your definition of a soft click? I have never heard that term before -- Google didn't yield any results for me either.

Comment: Can you please post html code for this button?